# Как передать название столбца таблицы в качестве аргумента функции?

Tags: python, mysql

К примеру есть функция которая выдаёт оставшиеся для игрока квесты одного из НПС. Первый аргумент название НПС, второй - имя игрока, по которому естественно должна идти проверка. Таблица на сервере хранит такие столбцы как имя зарегестрированного игрока и названия нпс со значениями по умолчанию (VARCHAR = "Список названий квестов через запятую"). Этих НПС очень много. Потому решено было сделать их не на отдельных таблицах, а качестве колонок, где для каждого игрока будет хранится свой список оставшихся квестов.

```
import datasql
import MySQLdb

def chek(npc, who):
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host=datasql.sql[0], user=datasql.sql[1],
                         passwd=datasql.sql[2], db=datasql.sql[3], charset=datasql.sql[4])
    cur = db.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute(
            "SELECT %s FROM quest_list WHERE name = %s", [npc, who])
        result = cur.fetchall()[0][0].split(',')
        if result == ['']:
            print("&#128077; Вы выполнили все задания этого НПС")
        else:
            cur.close()
            db.close()
            print("\n".join(result))
    except TypeError as e:
        print(f"Возникла неприятность '{e}' ")
```

И если вызвать эту функцию с существующими нпс и игроком в качестве аргументов, то ответом будет название нпс, вместо ожидаемого ответа на запрос. А если переписать функцию так:

```
import datasql
import MySQLdb

def chek(who):
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host=datasql.sql[0], user=datasql.sql[1],
                         passwd=datasql.sql[2], db=datasql.sql[3], charset=datasql.sql[4])
    cur = db.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute(
            "SELECT name_npc FROM quest_list WHERE name = %s", [who])
        result = cur.fetchall()[0][0].split(',')
        if result == ['']:
            print("&#128077; Вы выполнили все задания этого НПС")
        else:
            cur.close()
            db.close()
            print("\n".join(result))
    except TypeError as e:
        print(f"Возникла неприятность '{e}' ")
```

~ То выдаст ожидаемый результат, который и нужен был. Разве для колонок таблицы в запросе нельзя принимать вот такое выражение - %s? Оно принимается только по поиску значений в записях?
Если да, то как лучше поступить? НПС слишком много и неохото под каждого копипастить в коде одну и ту же функцию с одним лишь изменяемым значением в запросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это ожидаемое поведение, когда вы передаете параметр в запрос, БД подставляет значение параметра. Откуда ей знать, что вы в данном случае хотите, чтобы это трактовалось как имя колонки, а не значение (в этом месте синтаксически допустимо любое выражение, и константа и имя колонки)?

Напрямую это решается так, что нужно на стороне питона сгенерировать строку запроса с правильной колонкой:

Начиная с python 3.6

```
cur.execute(
    f"SELECT {npc} FROM quest_list WHERE name = %s", [who])
```

для более ранних версий:

```
cur.execute(
    "SELECT {} FROM quest_list WHERE name = %s".format(npc), [who])
```

Оба этих способа сгенерируют строку подставив в соответствующее место значение `npc`  еще до вызова метода `execute`.

Но по-хорошему, вашу задачу нужно решать нормализацией БД. То есть нужно изменить структура БД, а именно то, как хранятся названия заданий.

Имеет смысл создать новую таблицу `quest`:

```
CREATE TABLE quest (
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     player_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     npc_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL, -- имя НПС или другой идентификатор
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL, -- имя самого задания
     PRIMARY KEY (id),
     FOREIGN (player_name) KEY REFERENCES player(name),
     FOREIGN (npc_name) KEY REFERENCES npc(name) -- ссылка должна быть на уникальный 
                                                 -- идентификатор (первичный ключ)
                                                 -- тут я предположил, что это имя
);
```

Тогда в запросе не нужно будет делать манипуляций со строками:

```
select name
from quest
where user_name = %s and npc_name = %s
```

Comment: +1 за предложенную нормализацию -   приятно видеть вдумчивые ответы на SO)